# AWS synchronous/asynchronous flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have three steps in my AWS environment:

- **Step 1** is synchronous
- **Step 2** is executed after Step 1 and is asynchronous that takes input from Step 1 and encodes the audio file and puts the encoded file on S3.
- **Step 3** should execute after Step 2 takes input both from Step 1 and encoded file on S3 generated in Step 2.

How should I implement this? I want to use Step functions but I have asynchronous Step 2 that I am not sure how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by implementing Task [Activities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html).

> An activity worker can be an application running on an Amazon EC2
>   instance, an AWS Lambda function, a mobile device: any application
>   that can make an HTTP connection, hosted anywhere. When Step Functions
>   reaches an activity task state, the workflow waits for an activity
>   worker to poll for a task. An activity worker polls Step Functions by
>   using GetActivityTask, and sending the ARN for the related activity.
>   GetActivityTask returns a response including input (a string of JSON
>   input for the task) and a taskToken (a unique identifier for the
>   task). After the activity worker completes its work, it can provide a
>   report of its success or failure by using SendTaskSuccess or
>   SendTaskFailure. These two calls use the taskToken provided by
>   GetActivityTask to associate the result with that task.

Step 3 is supposed to be an activity task. Worker invoked in step 2 will poll activity created in Step 3 and after completing its job it will report Step 3 activity using [SendTaskSuccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskSuccess.html) or [SendTaskFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskFailure.html) depending on the output of the worker.

Comment: Why Step 3 is an activity task and not Step 2? Step 2 is asynchronous, step 3 is not.

Comment: One step in step functions can only use one resource. If step 2 is supposed to run an async worker job then it can not be used for activity job as well.